# Using ViewModel in Service

Tags: java, kotlin

How to get objects from the model view in the service?
I'm trying to get activity but i can't get activity in service.

```
 userUnitsViewModel.getAllUnits().observe(what in this palce?, Observer { t ->
            for (i in t) {

                if (i.category == "speed" && i.checked) {
                    Log.d("obj", i.toString())
                    speedUnitValue = i.value!!
                }
                if (i.category == "distance" && i.checked) {
                    Log.d("obj", i.toString())
                    distanceUnitValue = i.value!!
                }
                if (i.category == "altitude" && i.checked) {
                    Log.d("obj", i.toString())
                    altitudeUnitValue = i.value!!
                }
                if (i.category == "burn_mass" && i.checked) {
                    Log.d("obj", i.toString())
                    burnMassUnitValue = i.value!!
                }
                if (i.category == "weight") userWeight = i.value!!//waga
                if (i.category == "height") userHeight = i.value!!//wzrost
                if (i.category == "age") userAge = i.value!!//wiek
                if (i.category == "sex" && i.checked) userSex = i.name//plec
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LifecycleService` from `"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"` as parent for your service

```
class MyService : LifecycleService() {...}
```

and then you can use your service as `LifecycleOwner`

```
livedata.observe(this, ...)
```

Comment: But, im going to implement service class too, but in that view i can't do this. have you any solution for this problem?